# Automatic ticking checkbox in google sheet using google app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, checkbox

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGQYU.jpg)

I have a problem as follows.
First: on the holidays in column A respectively, I have colored the Order list table.

Second:In line F on holidays (in column A), no ticking in the check box
i tried it but not success
this is my code

```
function checkbox() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  if (sheet.getRange('C2').getValue() =='6/2/2021'||sheet.getRange('C2').getValue() 
     =='7/2/2021') {
                     sheet.getRange('C9').setValue('FALSE');
}   else {
            sheet.getRange('C9').setValue('FALSE');
         }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot understand about the relationship between your sample image and your script. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail of this? And, About your goal, you want to check all checkboxes at the row 9. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: is correct i want checll all checkboxes at the row 9 based on column A

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I couldn't understand about `based on column A`. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Comment: I have summarized the holidays in column A. Based on the data of column A the checkbox will not be checked. For example, in column A with the date "2021/3/6" or "2021/3/7" then cell H9 and cell I9 will not ticking and  Cell from "2021/03/01" to "2021/03/05" will be validated. And I want to do the same until the end of March. Looking forward to your help

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your replying, I cannot still understand about your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of the solution. I deeply apologize I cannot resolve your issue soon.

Comment: Hi @MiyagenCoLtd, based on my understanding, You want to uncheck the checkbox if the column date is listed as a holiday/weekend in column A. And if the current date where the checkbox was checked is not a holiday/weekend it should remain checked? (I did not fully understood this statement `"Cell from "2021/03/01" to "2021/03/05" will be validated."`). I would appreciate if you could share a sample sheet so we could provide sufficient support. [Share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383)

Comment: this is my link
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1H6waaBv1iO-ZY4qW2RlqpuGo-6JVjb5Ye9auifP6Qsk/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [onEdit(e)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) simple trigger to uncheck the checkbox if the date is a holiday.

---

### Pre-requisite:

- Make sure your Google Sheet Timezone and your Script Timezone is the same.

Upon checking your shared document, your Google Sheet Timezone is set to Tokyo(+09:00) but your Script timezone is set to `America/Los_Angeles`.

**To update your Script timezone:**

1. At the left, click `Project Settings setting`
2. Select the `Show "appsscript.json" manifest file in editor` checkbox.
3. Change the timeZone property in your `appsscript.json` file to `"timeZone": "Asia/Tokyo"`

---

### Sample Code:

```
function onEdit(e){

  var ss = e.source
  var sheetName = '注文記入表';
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var cell = e.range;

  Logger.log(cell.isChecked());
  //Check if modified cell is a checkbox and if it in sheet 注文記入表
  if(sheet.getName()==sheetName && cell.isChecked() != null){

    //Get Holidays
    var holidays = sheet.getRange('A1:A').getDisplayValues().flat().filter(String);

    //Get date value
    var dateVal = sheet.getRange(4,cell.getColumn()).getValue();
    Logger.log(dateVal);
    var dateStr = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(dateVal),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"dd/MM/yyyy");
    Logger.log(dateStr);

    //If current date is a holiday, uncheck the checkbox
    Logger.log(holidays.includes(dateStr));
    if(holidays.includes(dateStr)){
      cell.uncheck();
    }
  }

}
```

### What it does?

1. Get the [spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet) object and [range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) object using the [event objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) `e.source` and `e.range` respectively.
2. Check if the modified cell is in sheet '注文記入表' and if it is a checkbox using [range.isChecked()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#ischecked)

> **range.isChecked()**
>
> Returns whether all cells in the range have their checkbox state as 'checked'. Returns null if some cells are checked and the rest unchecked, or if some cells do not have checkbox data validation.

3. If the modified cell is a checkbox, get the list of holidays in column A. [range.getDisplayValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalues) returns a 2-d array of string values, use [Array.prototype.flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) to change it to 1-d array of string values. Then use [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to remove empty cell values.
4. Get the date of the checkbox using [range.getValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue). Since your holiday list of dates is in `DD/MM/YYYY` format, convert the date value in this format using [Utilities.formatDate(date, timeZone, format)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatdatedate,-timezone,-format)
5. Check if converted date in Step 4 is listed in your holiday array list using [Array.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes). If it is found in the holiday array list, un-check the checkbox using [range.uncheck()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#uncheck)

---

### Note:

- You cannot debug/run this onEdit() in the script editor manually. If you want to test this, you need to include logs in your code, edit a cell in your sheet and check the logs in the executions tab .

Comment: when  run your code An error occurred                                         `9:48:50 AM Error Type Error: Cannot read property 'source' of undefined`                                                                                    
 What can I do

Comment: Yes as mentioned in the answer under note, You cannot run the this function in the apps script editor since the event object 'e' don't exist yet. If you want to test the onEdit function you need to modify/edit a cell in your sheet to trigger this function with an event object